# Content Cuts Out Over the Fold using CSS3

Tags: html, mobile, css, overflow

I have a small web app I'm designing and I have a real weird problem. The inner content will always cut out below the page fold - you can't scroll down to read all of the text. I've tried this in Mobile Safari and on my desktop in Chrome/Firefox with no success.

The live URL is http://byjakewithlove.com/code/mobile-webapp/

Any suggestions I could try would help a lot. I basically have div with the ID **#content** and that holds the white BG and page text. I've got `overflow: auto;` which should create the scrollbar inside this div, and even have `height: 100%;`. I'm totally perplexed about what the issue is - again thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: seems like all of the text is readable. please clarify what's the problem.

Comment: @EliranMalka Yes I know it looks like that, but it is not all readable actually. I added a small image graphic at the very bottom of the content `div` so you can see what I mean. Refresh the page and tell me if you can see the graphic - if not, then not all the content is being display. Plus using `overflow: auto;` you should be able to scroll it all and this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can keep the `height: 100%` on the content element, but position the header element using absolute positioning (don't forget to set their parent's position to `relative`, of course) to stick it to the top, while setting a `padding` value to the content element that correlates with the header's height.

Comment: perfect! working on it now, I should have noticed that originally. thanks dude appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

the `height: 100%` is misused - "100%" refers to the container's height, so it's calculated for the parent, thus resulting this behavior.

simply omit the `height: 100%` declaration and set a fixed height.

Comment: but the problem is when I begin to load in new pages, the content will not be the same fixed height. I need it to be fluid or at least let me scroll within the content div.

Comment: And let me add that even setting the `height: 10000px;` does absolutely nothing. You can resize the window and more content will appear, but at no point will scrollbars appear. So using a fixed height isn't a solution at all, unfortunately.

Comment: i've changed it using the developer tools with the desired result, besides, what are you trying to achieve by setting `height: 10000px`? test it using a value smaller than the viewport, than you'll see its affect.